# php.ini settings marked for Win32 only are used on Linux

Tags: php, smtp, sendmail, ubuntu-16.04

The following settings within `/etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini` for mail are marked for Win32 only, but setting them appears to work fine on Ubuntu 16.04 / Apache 2.4.18:

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = mail.mymailhost.org
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 25
```

My system mail (sendmail) log also confirms that mail is able to be sent successfully. Can someone explain why these settings are allowed to be used on Linux hosts? Should I be setting them elsewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I have read that these settings are forwarded to sendmail, and the details of relaying the mail to the the SMTP host are handled there. So these settings don't seemed to be ignored on Linux systems, just handed off elsewhere to be dealt with.